# Hyperlink to the Logo in LaTeX style file

Tags: beamer

I have a LaTeX document and I want to add a hyperlink to the a log has the following command in my LaTeX document

```
\pgfdeclareimage[height=.5\@tempdimb]{logo}{mylogo}%
\logo{\pgfuseimage{logo}}%
```

The hyperlink I want to add could be written for example as follows:

```
\href{http://google.com}
```

Could you please help me how could I do that ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Maybe try `\href{www.google.com}{\pgfuseimage{logo}}`. If this does not work, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: The whole LaTeX files are found by this link: http://www.cs.ru.nl/P.Vullers/beamer.php

Comment: I am still new user for LaTex. Could you please tell me, how can I add it to the 1st LaTeX command lines. I meant, could you please write the whole all lines and how should I put them together.

Comment: Try with `\logo{\href{www.google.com}{\pgfuseimage{logo}}}`. But without a MWE this is just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

In general the syntax is `\href{website}{text displayed in the pdf}`. Instead of the text, you can also include images etc.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\logo{\href{www.google.com}{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

---

In your case, you probably want `\logo{\href{www.google.com}{\pgfuseimage{logo}}}`.